# Sending data from DataTables to Web API controller using POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I try to make server-side processing for [DataTables](https://datatables.net) using Web API. There are two actions in my Web API controller with same list of parameters:

```
public class CampaignController : ApiController
{
    // GET request handler
    public dtResponse Get(int draw, int start, int length)
    {
        // request handling
    }

    // POST request handler
    public void Post(int draw, int start, int length)
    {
        // request handling
    }
}
```

If I use GET method to send AJAX request to the server, the `Get` action is activated. However, if I use POST method, then neither action are activated.
I tried to change POST handler signature to

```
public void Post([FromBody]object value)
{
    // request handling
}
```

In this case the `value` is `null`. Note, the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` collection isn't empty. The `draw`, `start`, `length` variables are exist in this collection. Thus, I think the trouble is in model binding, but I cannot fix it. Help me, please.

Comment: POST endpoint is not suitable for multiple parameters. Use a binding object. I see you've changed that in the below snippet. Use a concrete type: class Diagram, prop draw, prop start, prop length.

Comment: Also add in verb attributes [HttpPost], [HttpGet] helps designing/building a restful API

Comment: @TezWingfield, I have tried to add verb attributes, but there's no any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what's going on, but appears there are a few missing elements. I've written a `Post endpoint` this morning, So hopefully will help pushing you in the right direction.

Also to note if you want "Data" use `Get`, if your inserting data then `POST`

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("orders")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]List<Models.Model.Order> orders)
        {

            if (orders == null)
                return BadRequest("Unusable resources.");

            if (validatedOrders.Count <= 0)
                return BadRequest("Unusable resources.");

            try
            {
                //Create abstracted Identity model to pass around layers
                var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                var identityModel = IdentityModel.Create(identity);
                if (identityModel == null)
                    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

                var response =  await _orderService.AddAsync(validatedOrders, identityModel);
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
            finally
            {
                _orderService.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

- Utilizing IHttpActionResult will expose the returning of a response
- Verb attributes helps with building/designing Restful API's and same
  name signatures
- Attribute Routing saves writing in the config and change routes in
  the class

To wrap it all up, replace the order collection with:

```
public sealed class Diagram
{
  public int Draw { get; set; } 
  public int Start { get; set; } 
  public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

Rewrite the validation, remove the Identity creation, remove the insert and remove/replace the attribute routing.

With `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` Try building a `Diagram object` from that and passing it up.

OR Alternatively passing in a `form collection`

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("something")]
 // POST api/<controller>
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(FormDataCollection form)
 {
     string tid = form.Get("tid");
     string sid = form.Get("sid");
     string userid = form.Get("userid");
     string udid = form.Get("udid");

  }
```

Additional resource from the **DataTable Docs**
[Git Hub Repo](https://gist.github.com/ChinhP/9b4dc1df1b12637b99a420aa268ae32b)

Comment: The spacial class `Diagram` together with [FromBody] attribute helped! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
[HttpPost]    
public void Post([FromBody]int draw, [FromBody]int start, [FromBody]int length)
{
    // request handling
}
```

Comment: The `[FromForm]` attribute сauses compilation error. Only [FromBody] and [FromUri] are working. What is namespace of  `[FromForm]` attribute?

Comment: [FromForm] is for Dot Net core. If you are using older .NET [FromBody] should work (updated answer)

Comment: Thanks, but does [FromBody] does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot have multiple "[FromBody]" defeats the purpose of being from the body of the request